# What is the difference between a *= 1 and a = +a?

Tags: javascript, int

What is the difference between

```
a *= 1;
```

and

```
a = +a;
```

in JavaScript?

Both convert a `string` to `number` (int or float). They behave differently from `parseInt` and `parseFloat`. But is there any difference between these two lines?

Comment: When you multiply string to 1 it converts string to number, and so does when you add + in front of string, so I need to know  what difference there is in converting.

Comment: There isn't any differences in this case. I could assume plus operation is faster then multiplication operation (bitwise) but it shouldn't have any noticeable affect when multiplying with 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any difference. They are both converted to numbers using a [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#table-11) conversion. And the numerical multiplication by 1 and unary plus operation keep the values the same.

Answer (score 3):

> What is difference between

```
a *= 1
```

This is Multiplication assignment, you are taking a and multiplying it by 1.

```
 a = +a
```

This is plain assignment, using the using the unary plus operator. It evaluates a and converts it into a number.

The main difference between the unary plus operator and parseInt or parseFloat is that the unary can convert string representations of both integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Where as parseInt and parseFloat can only convert string to int and float respectively.

Also the parseInt method allows you to set the radix (the base / mathematical numeral system) used. i.e.

```
parseInt(a, 10); //decimal numeral system
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, both try to convert the value to a number and assign either the value of the multiplication or the result of an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

By starting with an empty string, both results return `NaN`, if a stringed number or just a number the result is a number in both cases.

```js
var a, b;

a *= 1; 
b = +b;
console.log(a, b);

a = 'foo';
b = 'foo';

a *= 1; 
b = +b;
console.log(a, b);

a = '';
b = '';

a *= 1; 
b = +b;
console.log(a, b);

a = '7';
b = '7';

a *= 1; 
b = +b;
console.log(a, b);

a = 42;
b = 42;

a *= 1; 
b = +b;
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: So they're the same in these cases, now *What is difference between a *= 1 and a = +a*?

Comment: there is no difference.

Comment: empty string returns `0`. `undefined`returns `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the technical sense. But using the unary plus operator, that converts a string to a number might be definetly more obvious in this case, making your code more readable.